# Installed ubuntu on usb stick works fine on same laptop used for installation but does not boot on other machine it shows a blank screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, usb

Installed ubuntu 20.04 on a usb stick then used that to create a full ubuntu installation on a usb stick with 3 partitions swap, /boot & ex4 with a "/" 
Now the usb stick works well on the same laptop used to install ubuntu but on other machines it does not work it shows a blinking cursor on the left corner with a blank screen please help :)

Comment: This might happen if one computer is UEFI boot and the other is BIOS boot. See sudodus second reference if this is the problem. You might also need to reinstall GRUB, from the Live USB run: `sudo mount /dev/sdxy /mnt` then `sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdx` where sdxy is the root partition of the Full install USB.

Answer (score 0):

There can be different causes of this problem:

- You installed the bootloader into the internal drive. This can be avoided if you unplug, disconnect or otherwise disable the internal drive during the installation to the external drive.
- There is no hardware driver for the other computer(s). This can happen for example if you install a proprietary graphics driver, that does not work in the other computer(s) and blocks the built-in linux driver that should be used.

See the following links,

- [Step-wise instructions for installed system in a USB drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312)
- [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step/)
- [If you need not encrypt the drive, there is an easy alternative. You can use a compressed image](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2447539&p=13974203#post13974203)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer.
I have tried following this but it didn't work still i'm not able to boot full ubuntu with usb stick everything works fine in the machine which i used to install the ubuntu on usb
For partitions in usb i have used swap - logical, efi - primary & selecting this as boot loader & ex4 - primary

Comment: @MirzaAreebBaig, *Please edit your original question* to explain with *more details* which *method* you used to install Ubuntu. And the *result*: what works, and what does not work. And *describe the computers* where you want to run from the USB drive: brand name and model for each of them. - In other words, please help me help you.